# Whats wrong >?i cant do

Tags: java, android, database, nullpointerexception, callback

but something wrong,im new.
My code

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //kluci dla soedenenia
    public static final String APPI_ID = "----------------------";
    public static final String SECRET_KEY = "----------------";
    public static final String VERSION = "---";
    //moy log
    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //soedenil backendless
        Backendless.initApp(this, APPI_ID, SECRET_KEY, VERSION);

        Customer melinda = new Customer();
        melinda.setFirstName( "Melinda" );
        melinda.setLastName( "Grey" );
       Backendless.Persistence.of(Customer.class).save(melinda, new AsyncCallback<Customer>() {
           @Override
           public void handleResponse(Customer response) {

           }

           @Override
           public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

           }
       });
        System.out.println("Melinda's rate is "+melinda.getDiscountRatePercent()+"percent");
                melinda.setDiscountRatePercent( melinda.getDiscountRatePercent() + 2 );
        Backendless.Persistence.of(Customer.class).save(melinda, new AsyncCallback<Customer>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(Customer customer) {

            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

            }
        });
        Customer updatedMelinda = new Customer();
        updatedMelinda.setFirstName( "Melinda" );
        updatedMelinda.setLastName( "Grey" );

        updatedMelinda = Backendless.Persistence.of( Customer.class ).findById
                ( melinda.getID() );
        System.out.println("Now Melinda's discount rate is "+updatedMelinda.
                getDiscountRatePercent() +" percent.");

    }
        }
```

Customer class

```html
public class Customer {
    private String lastName;
    private Integer discountRatePercent;
    private String firstName;
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName( String lastName )
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public Integer getDiscountRatePercent()
    {
        return discountRatePercent;
    }
    public void setDiscountRatePercent( Integer discountRatePercent )
    {
        this.discountRatePercent = discountRatePercent;
    }
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName( String firstName )
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

My java wrong

> 10-22 03:14:23.620 2774-2774/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.example.elvir.subdexample, PID: 2774
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.elvir.subdexample/com.example.elvir.subdexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                        at com.example.elvir.subdexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: No, I looked ((((

Comment: post your `mainactivity`

Comment: okey Sir wait plz

Comment: point to the line number 40 in your code

Comment: melinda.setDiscountRatePercent( melinda.getDiscountRatePercent() + 2 );

Comment: ???whats wrong here?

Comment: seems like this `melinda.getDiscountRatePercent()` is giving you null value or this line has some null value in it's fields

Comment: Corrected possible?

Comment: at this `com.example.elvir.subdexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)` line you have to look for null values

Comment: can you shoü me correct ansüer im new in java

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
updatedMelinda = Backendless.Persistence.of( Customer.class ).findById
            ( updatedMelinda );
```

by

```
updatedMelinda = Backendless.Persistence.of( Customer.class ).findById
            ( melinda.getID() );
```

Comment: full code would be more helpful.

Comment: Java screaming red "getID"i a

Comment: i add full code

Comment: There is a problem with your model and logic. Follow this example:
https://github.com/Backendless/RestaurantToGo/blob/master/location_listing/src/main/java/com/backendless/samples/restaurant/entities/Restaurant.java.